# query for between 2 time in 2 database table in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

query for between 2 time in 2 database table in PHP and MYSQL

this is my database

```
| time1   | time2 |
| 15:00   | 17:00 |
```

then i want to show if it is already has a time between 2 database table in Query code

for example

```
 $a = '14:00';
 $b = '16:00';
if($a <= $time1 && $b >=$time2){
   echo 'it already has a time in the database';

 }else{
 echo 'dont have time in the database';
  }

 output will be
  it already has a time in the database
```

Thanks in advance
i want a query for that sample. thanks again

Comment: `WHERE '$a' <= time1 AND '$b' >= time2`

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE '$a' >= time2 OR '$b' <= time1`

Comment: What is the whole query you tried and what is the result?

Comment: for example time1 = 15:00 and time2 = 1700 then the $a = 14:00 and $b=1600. it means 15:00 to 16:00 is in between of $a and $b and it will echo it was in the middle of time if is not i will echo you can save that time.

Comment: this is my wrong query. Select * from database where time1 >= $a AND time2<= $b

Answer (score 0):

i think you are comparing the wrong data types... Witch data type are you using inside your mysql ? (time , datetime, string ...)

If (it's 'time' change your code like so):

```
$a = strtotime('14:00');
```

and compare it then.

Else { please provide your database data type.}